# Amazon cloud search - query for products for range of prices/sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, cloud

How can I create a query in which I ask for products (i.e from clothes store) for a range of prices, i.e products from 10 Euro to 20 Euro.
What is the syntax for such a query?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for such a search is, for example: `10..20`